# Как отредактировать переменные get-запроса для отправки в виде массива?

Tags: javascript

Есть два GET запроса, один правильный, но не из моего скрипта и выглядит он так:

Query String Parameters:

```
contentType:text/html; charset=utf-8
cs[]:Имя 
cs[]:Телефон 
cs[]:Вопрос 
cs[]:Ваш вопрос
cs[]:Подарочная упаковка
cs[]:Источник трафика
cs[]:Страница с запросом
os[]:1111111111
os[]:1222222222
os[]:3333333333333
os[]:Узнать наличие
os[]:Нет
os[]:http://proworking.ru/
os[]:http://proworking.ru/#!slide-6
ctime:0
idr:6070121132
dmn:proworking.ru
```

А в моем скрипте запрос выглядит так:

```
contentType:text/html; charset=utf-8
cs:Имя ,Телефон ,Вопрос ,Ваш вопрос,Время звонка,Подарочная упаковка,Источник трафика,Страница с запросом
os:aaaaa,dddddddd,ffffffffff,,с 10 до 12 час.,Нет, //proworking.ru/, proworking .ru/filaret.html
ctime:0
idr:6070121132
dmn:proworking .ru
```

этот вариант не устраивает...

Вот код с которого происходит неправильный запрос:

```
  var data = {
              contentType: "text/html; charset=utf-8",
              cs: cs,
              os: os,
              ctime: cnt,
              idr:"'.$faction.'",
              dmn:document.domain
  };

  var dataStr = Object.keys(data).map(function(key){ 
    return encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[key]); 
  }).join("&");

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", getScriptFolder("callback_st_of.js") + "lib/send.php?"+dataStr, true);

  request.onload = function(i) {
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
      // Success!
        var i = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        cmeMsg(i.cls,i.message);    
        if (i.result == "success") {
                  setCookie("callme-sent", i.time);
                  jQuery(".cme-btn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                  dl("cmeHide", 4);
                  dl("cmeClr", 5);
        }
    } else {
      // We reached our target server, but it returned an error

    }
  };

  request.onerror = function() {
    // There was a connection error of some sort
  };

  request.send()};
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как его переделать, чтобы он отправлял запрос в правильном виде?

Comment: приведите пример содержимого вот этих вещей - cs: cs,
              os: os,
              ctime: cnt, скорее всего вам надо будет отдельно перебрать массивы os и cs,чтобы конвертировать их для запроса. Если это массивы,конечно.

Comment: А в примере где неправильно настроенный запрос текст из гугл хрома -cs:Имя ,Телефон ,Вопрос ,Ваш вопрос...  - это как бы не содержимое ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну так ты ведь  сам же и присваиваешь cs=cs, os=os и приводишь к виду ?cs=cs&os=os :

```
var data = { [...]  cs: cs,  os: os 
[...]
encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[key]);
```

в итоге, у тебя получается что-то вроде `cs=a,b,c&os=d,e`, где a,b,c и d,e - это, все равно, строки

Тебе надо либо сначала разбивать cs и os, преобразуя их в нечто подобное массиву (т.е. уже не cs=a,b,c а попробовать, например, что-нибудь вроде `cs[]=a&cs[]=b&cs[]=c` или нечто в таком роде),
либо уже после получения запроса бить os и cs на массивы

**upd:** 
Вот один вариант (замени конструкцию  var dataStr = [...]; этим)

```
var getDataStr = function(arr, key_name, level){ 
    return Object.keys(arr).map(function(key){ 
    var v=arr[key]; if(typeof v=='string'){v=v.split(","); if(v.length>1){arr[key]=v;}} 
   if(typeof arr[key] == 'object'){return getDataStr(arr[key], key+'[]');}else{  return ((typeof key_name!=='undefined')?(key_name + "=") : (key + "=") )+ encodeURIComponent(arr[key]);}
  }).join("&");
  }
 var dataStr = getDataStr(data);
```

Это лишь один из возможых путей. Задача не сколько в самом JS сколько в логике алгоритма: понять что и откуда должно приходить, на что раскладываться и куда уходить, чтобы из одной строки получить другую. Возможно, к примеру, при помощи поиска/замены в строке всех вхождений , на '&'+key+'[]=' данный пример можно решить еще проще. Либо, обработкой на стороне сервера разбивая поступающие переменные $cs= explode(',',$_GET['cs']); - тот же эффект будет

Comment: Я конечно понимаю что мне надо это сделать , я по сути вопрос свой и задаю о том как это сделать . Юзал всегда жиквери а в javascript особо не селен , не могу я так просто взять и сотворить с объектами и массивами такое что бы работало как надо, два дня мучаюсь. Не поможете ли до конца раз уж начали ?

Comment: Это задача не сколько знания js сколько логики: нужно понять последовательность действий, необходимую для получения результата, разложить на более простые шаги, а конкретные функции для реализации того или другого уже не сложно потом найти. Я тебе добавил в ответ один из возможных вариантов решения, для данной задачи. Вообще, того же результата можно было бы достичь ограничившись и даже менее замысловатыми функциями - главное, понять логику и последовательость простых  действий (шагов)